# Alternative ways to write the gradient

Tags: derivatives, gradient-descent

This may not be the right forum to ask this question, but suppose that I have a multi-dimensional function $L$, and I want to compute its gradient w.r.t. a set of parameters $\theta$, where $[|\theta| > 1]$. I saw in several texts that they write it down as:

$$
\nabla_{\theta}L
$$

However, $\nabla_{\theta}L$ occupies too much page width, i.e. if $\theta$ includes other qualifications such as $\theta_{i,t}$. Since am writing using a two column paper format, I want to conserve on text width, but I can take up more spaces height-wise. Is it correct to write the gradient this way?

$$
\frac{\nabla_{L}}{\nabla{\theta}}
$$

or does it make sense if I stick to using partial derivative notations, i.e.

$$
\frac{\partial{L}}{\partial{\theta}}
$$

Comment: I think that the first would be understood at componentwise division of the gradient of $L$ by the gradient of $\theta$ in the best case. The second would be understood as a scalar or vector partial derivative (check out matrix calculus), so I do not believe that any of these fit your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write it as 
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta},$$
because that's what the $\theta$ component of the gradient means, by definition.